# How can I add a button in Google Spreadsheets so that one person can click it only once?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for any changes in app script that will make this happen.
I've already made a button and assigned the correct function to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PropertiesService to store user specific data.

```
    var properties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    var buttonStatus = properties.getProperty("buttonStatus");

      if(!buttonStatus){

          //code to be executed after clicking the button

          properties.setProperty("buttonStatus", "clicked");
          return;

      }

      //code to be executed when user clicks the button multiple times (e.g. displaying notification)

      return;
}
```